# How to add column name to my java table? (from database)

Tags: java, swing, postgresql

Hi so i was wondering why my the Jtable didnt have any column title however it does have the data from my postgres db
I want to be able to choose a column title for each data

```
public class aaaaa extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private static JTable table;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Connection c = null;
 Statement stmt = null;
 try{
  Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
  c = DriverManager
     .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MovieDatabase",
     "postgres", "password");
    c.setAutoCommit(false);
    System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

     stmt = c.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM film" );
    table = new JTable(buildTableModel(rs));

     while ( rs.next() ) {
     int filmid = rs.getInt("filmid");
     String  filmtitle = rs.getString("filmtitle");
     int filmyear  = rs.getInt("filmyear");
     String  filmgenre = rs.getString("filmgenre");

     System.out.println( "ID = " + filmid );
     System.out.println( "TITLE = " + filmtitle );
     System.out.println( "YEAR = " + filmyear );
     System.out.println( "GENRE = " + filmgenre );

     System.out.println();
 }
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  c.close();
 }catch ( Exception e ) {
  System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
  System.exit(0);
}

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                aaaaa frame = new aaaaa();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public aaaaa() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 411);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);


    table.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 350);
    contentPane.add(table);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 350);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);
}

public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)
        throws SQLException {

    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

    // names of columns
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
        columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
    }

    // data of the table
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
            vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
        }
        data.add(vector);
    }

    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

}
}
```

[image]

Thanks for ur help.

Comment: What happens when you change `return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);` to `return new DefaultTableModel(data, new Object[]{"1","2","3","4"});`? If you suddenly have columnnames, then you should check, if `metaData.getColumnNames(column)` might be empty.

Comment: when i changed it i got this error  " The constructor 
 DefaultTableModel(Vector<Vector<Object>>, Object[]) is 
 undefined "

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Looked at the wrong Constructor. Can you try this: `Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();` ...
`columnNames.add("Column 1"); `... with adding 3 more columns? Basically you will be hard-coding the column names.

Comment: it doesnt do anything...when i put the other 3 columns got an error

Comment: By the way getColumnLabel might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You are using your table outside of a scrollpane. If you really wish to use the JTable in a standalone view, you can get the headers using `getTableHeader()`:

`JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();`

And then add the `header` to where you want it to be.

The other, more prefered, way would be to simply add the table to a scrollpane:

`contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(table));`

See here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html

> Note that if you wish to use a JTable in a standalone view (outside of a JScrollPane) and want the header displayed, you can get it using getTableHeader() and display it separately.

Comment: I kind of understand what you mean but im sorry if this is a dumb question,where is contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(table)); supposed to be placed?

Comment: nvm,I actually got it,i removed the "setLayout(null)" and It worked. btw i would like to ask a question if it is ok..what would happen to my table when it becomes too large,does a scrollbar appear at the side and how would i view the rest of the values? thank u so much anyway

Comment: Please never use `setLayout(null)`, this is a pretty dirty way to handle layout and has severe side effects. Better use a LayoutManager like `MigLayout`. ... you can use `HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED` or  `HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS` or `HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER`. This controls if and how you will see scrollbars. Read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html ... if my answer is sufficient, please accept it. Else change your question so we can work out what is missing. :)

Comment: actually,i have 2 java classes in my project,this one and a GUI class, the GUI class contains all the buttons and the button-"View all" is supposed to open this class JFrame, But when i click the View All button it opens a JFrame that has nothing on it (its supposed to show this table)...do u think its because i removed the setLayout(null)? How can i fix this?

Comment: The frame now probably has no more layout, so write this: `setLayout(new MigLayout())` and `contentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout());`